# Find $[3T^{n+2} + 3T^{n+1} + 3T^{n}]_{B}$ where $T(a,b,c) = (b,c,a)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a linear transformation: $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined as: 
$$T(a,b,c) = (b,c,a)$$
And a basis $B = \{(0,1,0), (1,0,0), (0,0,1)\}$.

I need to find $[3T^{n+2} + 3T^{n+1} + 3T^{n}]_{B}$ , where $n \in \mathbb{N}$
I see that it doesn't matter what the value of $n$ is, in the end I will get $(a, b, c) + (b, c, a) + (c, a, b)$ (not necessarilly in that order but it doesn't matter since addition is commutative). So in the end I got that:

$[3T^{n+2} + 3T^{n+1} + 3T^{n}]_{B} = 3[[(a + b + c), (a + b + c), (a + b + c)]]_{B}$
But all the other students got to this final solution somehow:$\begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 3 & 3 \\
    3 & 3 & 3 \\
    3 & 3 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$

Why is that? Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct. The matrix represents the transformation in just another manner.

For the vectors of the basis $(0, 1, 0)$, $(1, 0, 0)$, $(0, 0, 1)$, it identically evaluates to $(3, 3, 3)$ which as a linear combination can be written as $3(0, 1, 0) + 3(1,0, 0) + 3(0, 0, 1)$. A linear map $\mathcal T :U\to V$can be uniquely determined by its matrix $\mathcal M(\mathcal T)$, which is really just a table that tells you where each member of the basis in $U$ maps to each member of the basis in $V$. That matrix $\mathcal M(\mathcal T)$ is given by the following:$$\begin{matrix}
    &\small (0, 1, 0) & \small(1, 0, 0) & \small(0, 0, 1) \\
    \small (0, 1, 0) & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
    \small(1, 0, 0)&3 & 3 & 3 \\
    \small (0, 0, 1)&3 & 3 & 3
\end{matrix}$$

Comment: I'm very new to linear algebra (about three days). So if I got some part of the terminology wrong, please comment.